# how convert the usd to other currency using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need php coding for convert the USD TO ALL LOCAL CURRENCY.i find the lot of link
stock overflow but they not working .especially this(https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$amount&from=$from&to=$to) link not working kindly give the solution of my problem

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple method to convert currency in php using google API

```
function currencyConverter($from_currency, $to_currency, $amount) {
  $from_Currency = urlencode($from_currency);
  $to_Currency = urlencode($to_currency);
  $encode_amount = urlencode($amount);
  $get = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/finance/converter?a=$encode_amount&from=$from_Currency&to=$to_Currency");
  $get = explode("<span class=bld>",$get);
  $get = explode("</span>",$get[1]);
  $converted_currency = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", null, $get[0]);
  return $converted_currency;
}
```

For more details about [Currency Converter](https://www.phpflow.com/php/currency-converter-in-php-using-google-api/)

Comment: this is not working @billal ahmed